# Algebraic invariant theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Deal all, I am looking for a gentle introduction to algebraic invariant theory (for a Bachelor project) with some simple (but interesting) applications in representation theory (of finite groups, of Lie algebras).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Procesi's "Lie groups" book and his primer with Kraft ( https://math.unibas.ch/~kraft/Papers/KP-Primer.pdf ) ?

Comment: The primer is more condensed. The book is probably easier in some parts.

Answer (score 1):

A good book is the book *Lie Groups*, An Approach through Invariants and Representations" by Claudio Procesi. This contains algebraic invariant theory, Lie algebras, representations of finite groups and of Lie algebras, and much more. It should be ideal for your purpose.

Comment: Many thanks Dietrich, I found also some useful books: Bernd Sturmfels, Algorithms in Invariant Theory. 
Gurevich, Foundations of the theory of algebraic invariants. 
Igor Dulgachev, Lectures on invariant theory.